# How to initiate another field value to a field without taking input in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two fields approved_budget and budget_balance. I take input approved_budget and want to initiate the value of budget_balance as approved_budget. More specifically, If I take 1000 as approved_budget then my approved_budget value will be set as 1000 initially.

```
fieldset.form-group
  label Approved budget
  = f.text_field  :approved_budget, steps: :any,
          class: 'form-control form-control-sm input-sm', required: true
```

Comment: You need to use javascript for this

Comment: Hi Riaz, when you say that you want to initiate the other field's value do you mean that the `budget_balance` field should reflect whatever value the user put in the `approved_budget ` and that the user should be able to edit that field in the form?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.text_field :approved_budget, id: "approved_budget", onkeyup: 'myFunction()' %>
<%= f.text_field :budget_balance, id: "budget_balance" %>
```

Use the following in your script

```
  <script>
     function myFunction() {
       document.getElementById('budget_balance').value = document.getElementById('approved_budget').value;
     }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a callback that observes updates on the `approved_budget` field and sets the value on the `budget_balance` field.
Add the below logic in the model:

```
before_save :assign_budget_balance

def assign_budget_balance
  self.budget_balance = approved_budget
end
```